# Is there a bijection between [0,1] and S?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $S$?

$$S=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}:\forall p \in \mathbb{Z}\left[ x\right], p\left( x\right) \neq 0\right\}$$

I need some help characterizing the set $S$.

EDIT: I understand that $\mathbb{R}$ is bijective to $[0,1]$. Furthermore, I understand that $\mathbb{Z}\left[ x\right]$ is countable (also, zero polynomial is probably not included here) and, since it has finitely many roots, the set of all possible roots of all such polynomials is countable. I was just missing the fact that this set *is* $\mathbb{R}\ - S $ and then $S$ is countable.

Thank you for the fast responses!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}\left[ x\right]$ here?

Comment: polynomials with integer coefficients

Comment: So the $S$ is empty because of zero polynomial!

Comment: $\mathcal Z[X]$ is countable, and each nonzero polynomial has only finitely many roots, so $\mathbb R-S$ is countable.  Since $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, it follows that $S$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$ and therefore as $[0,1]$. ("Non-zero" is there to take care of @GhD's correction of the problem statement.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a bijection.  $S$ is the complement of the set of [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number).  The set of algebraic numbers is countable, so $|S|=\mathfrak c=|[0,1]|$

Comment: This is probably the intended answer, though as pointed out in a comment it would technically require the condition that only non-zero polynomials be considered.